# Define class "Object" in global namespace

Tags: php

I am writing a library that provides object-oriented approach to php's native types - array, string, integer etc.

Also, the library will provide an abstract `Object` class that the programmer may extend to gain some nice features in their objects (mostly class and instance introspection).

**The concern:** I am tempted to define the `Object` class in the global namespace.

I understand that this is generally considered bad practice but given the nature of my library I feel like an exception could possibly be made.

**The question:**

How would you, as a potential user, react to seeing this base class defined in the global namespace? Do you consider the above as a valid reason to define a single class in the global namespace?

Comment: Is there any reason it *has* to be in the global namespace? What about `SW\String`, `SW\Array`, `SW\Object` etc?

Comment: I am only considering the class `Object` to be in global namespace. And it does not necessarily have to be there - I would just like to hear people's opinion. The reason behind it is that it makes more sense to use it without the namespace specified or without having to import the namespace. It just feels... natural. But I would prefer that the library does not break *too many* (I know, that's relative) existing libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Namespaces are there to solve exactly that problem: giving code with generic, possibly conflicting naming a place to live. "Object" is about as generic as it gets, conflicts are likely. The choice seems pretty obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

As per PSR recommendations, you should not put anything into the global namespace. If you are writing a library, you should consider reading up on PSR recommendations, that way you can make sure that your library will behave nicely with most other libraries.